# How to find a zip file, unzip it, find a specific file in it using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to 
1) Find a zipfile at a particular directory location
2) If it exists then unzip it
3) Out of its contents find a specific file and move it to other directory.

```
def searchfile():
for file in os.listdir('/user/adam/datafiles'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'abc.zip'):
        return True
return False
```

if searchfile():

```
print('File exists')
```

else:

```
print('File not found')
```

def file_extract():

```
    os.chdir('/user/adam/datafiles')
    file_name = 'abc.zip'
    destn = '/user/adam/extracted_files'
    zip_archive = ZipFile (file_name)
    zip_archive.extract('class.xlsx',destn)
    print("Extracted the file")
    zip_archive.close()
```

search_file

file_extract

When I execute the above script, it shows no compile time issues or runtime issues,. but it just works for the first function. When I check for the files in the extracte_files folder I don't see the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you have never actually called `searchfile()`, and even if you had, `found` would still not be defined if `abc.zip` is not matched.

If you want to have file searching in a separate function (which is a good idea), you may be better off having it *return* a success/failure boolean instead of relying on a global variable.

So you may want something like this: (Note: code not tested)

```
import os
import fnmatch
import zipfile

def searchfile():
        for file in os.listdir('/user/adam/datafiles'):
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'abc.zip'):
                        return True  # <-- Note this
        return False  # <-- And this

if searchfile():  # <-- Now call the function and use its return value
        print('File exists')
else:
        print('File not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

The only place you define `found` is in the `if` block, so if `abc.zip` is not found, `found` will be undefined. But moreover, even if `abc.zip` is found and `found` is defined, it is defined as a local variable to `searchfile()`, and your main scope won't have access to it. You should initialize it as a global variable in the main scope, and declare it as a global variable in `searchfile()` so that modifications to it can be reflected in the main scope:

```
def searchfile():
    global found
    for file in os.listdir('/user/adam/datafiles'):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'abc.zip'):
            found = True

found = False
searchfile()
if found:
    print('File exists')
else:
    print('File not found')
```

But the use of global variable really isn't necessary since you can simply return `found` as a returning value from `searchfile()`:

```
def searchfile():
    for file in os.listdir('/user/adam/datafiles'):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'abc.zip'):
            return True
    return False

if searchfile():
    print('File exists')
else:
    print('File not found')
```